# Does the .NET Framework perform internal checks before changing specific properties?

Tags: c#, winforms, optimization

In quite a few cases I happen to be in a situation that I was wondering if I had to perform an IF check before setting a variable (and increase the method's complexity) or if this is done internal by Windows or the Framework.

As an example, assume we have an event that is being trigger constantly such as the Form's `MouseMove` event. Which one of those methods would be better to use ? Is calling `this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;` being check internally as well to ensure that no action will take place if it is not needed or does it blindly execute the code ?

**Example A:**

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X - this.Width > -16 && e.Y - this.Height > -16)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    }
    else
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
}
```

**Example B:**

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.X - this.Width > -16 && e.Y - this.Height > -16)
    {
        if (this.Cursor != Cursors.SizeNWSE)
            this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (this.Cursor != Cursors.Arrow)
            this.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're concerned about performance? Why don't you test it yourself, see if the `if` is redundant or not.

Comment: Not sure if performance like the above example can be measured as it must be extremely small. I am trying to find out if there are internal checks that check if a code should be executed (in this case, changing the cursor) or if we should always do the checks ourselves.

Comment: It is safe to assign it blindly, and does not harm performance as well.

Comment: I take it back. Ran some tests. See answer in a few minutes.

Comment: I wasn't sure either, by the way. But I chose to check, just in case (as you should, apparently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short:** Yes, making the check is most efficient by much.

**In depth:**

I've tested and compared (the code runs on the Form's Load event), and was surprised to see an actual difference.

Here is the code I've used to test:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;

var sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
}
sw1.Stop();

var sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
{
    if (this.Cursor != Cursors.SizeNWSE)
    {
        this.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
    }
}
sw2.Stop();
```

And then I swapped between the two, running the second case before the first, just to be sure. And the results are certain!

> With If: 00:00:00.8065328
>
> Without If: 00:00:20.8631726

A huge difference! Running without the check was more than 20 times slower than running with the check.

This means that when assigning a Cursor, there is no check to determine if the assignment can be ignored.

But what happens if the assignment really can't be ignored? What if it's a different Cursor each time?

Good question! The answer is that further testing shows very little difference between the yes-check and the no-check versions, when the cursors assigned are NEVER the same as the actual cursor at the moment of the assignment, so the assignment was never redundant. The difference was obviously the extra time it took to perform the checks.

ReSharper may warn you that the check is redundant ("Redundant check before assignment") but is isn't, in this case! Certainly not.

If you're doing it a LOT, you want to make the check.

On a MouseMove event, I would suggest making the check, to prevent laggy mouse. Even if you don't notice it, it might show on slower machines.

Comment: In other words, setting the cursor takes 0.002 milliseconds. So if you're just doing it once, no need to bother with the check. If, on the other hand, you're setting the cursor ten million times in the same event handler... well, you mostly likely have bigger problems to solve. :P

Comment: It was obvious that the difference will be small, but if this happens on every MouseMove, in some situations with busier CPU's and slower machines, it can make a difference. Are you surprised that a test is being ran a million times for an accurate comparison?

Comment: I'm not surprised to see the test being run ten million times, no. That's a sensible way to determine average execution time. I don't think the test provides a compelling reason to add the check, however, because in reality every MouseMove event only takes an extra 0.002 ms, which is unlikely to be noticeable. Avoid premature optimization: if you *do* observe laggy mouse movement, *then* make the change.

Comment: People always say that around SO. Avoid premature optimizations. It's really bad. Don't get me wrong - you're right, avoid them. But you people always assume that these are premature. What if they aren't? Anyways, I'm an efficiency freak. This answer is here for other efficiency freaks. Others, probably have very little interest in checking this question out in the first place.

Comment: An optimization is premature if it is made before one proves it's needed. I am respectfully disagreeing with your apparent assessment that, because setting a cursor ten million times takes a non-trivial amount of time, adding the check to MouseMove is warranted.

Comment: Your result is incorrect, the difference you are seeing is due to something else. 2 microseconds is within "calling a function" levels of overhead. And the internals of `Cursor` do check before doing anything.

Comment: @Guvante Wrong. I've tested and the "calling a function" overhead is nearly nothing, even on a million times scale. The internals of `Cursor` do check before invoking the CursorChanged event, but that doesn't skip their whole "cursor assigning" code. As you can see the decompiled code in a different answer, the 2nd `if` will be executed even if `cursor1 == value`.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Did you actually put together a test that avoided the JIT taking over? Was your test making a function call across page boundaries? In either case, please don't claim that 2 microseconds is significant, no one changes their cursor 50,000 times in a row (the number of iterations required to get a delay of 1/10th of a second)

Comment: You do have a point, by I still rather keep the CPU free from useless work, even if just a little useless work.

Comment: @YoryeNathan: Premature optimization is the cause of a lot of hardship. You are increasing the complexity of your code (which is by far the most important detail of your codebase) for a beyond pointless change in performance. Additionally the extra work you mention may even be beneficial, since you don't know offhand what that code does.

Answer (score 2):

No. Why would it? There's absolutely no reason for .NET to behave like that. Comparing something before assigning to prevent “overwriting” the same value just increases complexity and perhaps decreases performace—and we are speaking about micro-micro-microoptimizations here. The real performance micro-impact depends largely on the behavior of the particular destination CPU architecture, caches, timing, locality a many other factors.

The only reason for such a check would be if *any* assignment would trigger an action (in your example `Cursor` denoting a property) which would be unwanted in case the exactly same value would already have been store in the particular property.

Hence if you need such behavior, I would recommend encapsulating it into the property's setter:

```
public Cursors Cursor
{
    get { return cursor; }
    set
    {
        // prevent reacting to “no change”
        if (cursor != value)
        {
            cursor = value;
            … perform some other action …
        }
    }
}
private Cursors cursor;
```

To conclude, don't worry about performance, worry about semantics and readability of your code.

---

**UPDATE:** When running the test code provided in another answer, my results are approximately **between 00:00:00.0800000 and 00:00:00.1500000** on Core i5 3320M 2.60 GHz CPU. My `cursor` is declared as local variable. It's important to note, that sometimes the unconditional version is faster, and sometimes the conditional is faster.

If, in the OPs case, it is declared as a property (the OP states it's a 'variable') which involves some complex internal process, then yes, the version with a conditional assignment might be significantly faster. However, the OPs question didn't indicate that.

In a real-world software I doubt there will be so many cursor change that it's worh thinking about performance for a single second.

Comment: Encapsulating the check is a great idea, but this isn't what the issue is. The thing is that there is actually indeed a big difference in performance, so the check isn't redundant after all. The `Cursor` assignment leads to functions that do full cursor-changing work without checking if they really need to. See my answer.

Comment: I think you're missing the point that the OP doesn't own the property. It's all Framework's stuff. Also, there is a big difference between our results. What is the Target Framework on which you built the code? I'm intrigued.

Comment: The target framework is irrelevant. (.NET 4.5 if you need to know it…)

Comment: It might be, since they may have made changes in the `Cursor` related code in the Framework, right? I've checked on 3.0, 3.5 and 4, and I see a big difference. Could you please upload the full project that contains the test, so I can examine differences?

Comment: I've just reread your answer and stumbled upon this: "My cursor is declared as local variable." - This is a complete different test. In OP's example he is referring to the Form's property, which causes further code to run in the `Set` block. The difference is obvious if you ran it on a local `Cursor myCursor` variable. This discussion isn't about check vs dont-check in general, but specifically regarding Framework properties and variables. The word "variable" may have confused you to think this is a local variable, but people use it in many ways, even if other words describe the thing better.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET framework does not check the property before setting it.  Here is the decompiled code snippet for setting the `Cursor` of a `Form`:

```
      set
      {
        Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor) this.Properties.GetObject(Control.PropCursor);
        Cursor cursor2 = this.Cursor;
        if (cursor1 != value)
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.IntSecurity.ModifyCursor.Demand();
          this.Properties.SetObject(Control.PropCursor, (object) value);
        }
        if (this.IsHandleCreated)
        {
          System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.POINT pt = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.POINT();
          System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.RECT rect = new System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods.RECT();
          System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetCursorPos(pt);
          System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowRect(new HandleRef((object) this, this.Handle), out rect);
          if (rect.left <= pt.x && pt.x < rect.right && (rect.top <= pt.y && pt.y < rect.bottom) || System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetCapture() == this.Handle)
            this.SendMessage(32, this.Handle, (IntPtr) 1);
        }
        if (cursor2.Equals((object) value))
          return;
        this.OnCursorChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
      }
    }
```

You can see that there is a bunch of code executed every time.  There is check to see if the property has changed, but it only stops the framework from running a few lines.

Comment: While I like your summary, I am unsure if posting decompiled code is something that Microsoft allows for their DLLs...